# How do i do the Boethiah's calling quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm in the middle of the quest where you are supposed to sacrifice a follower, I got the drunk guy from Silver Blood Inn to come with me, but when i try to command him to use the pillar, he just stands there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why its not working for you, when you talk to him does he have the option that says *'I need you to do something for me'*. If not then go pay a mercenary and have them touch the alter, they usually have that option.